# How do You Make the Brush Falloff be a Bump Function?

Tags: mathematics, brushes

If I do use a brush in Blender, then there is a *Falloff* option.

How do you make the *Falloff* be a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)?

Also, I do not want an approximation of bump function made by moving around the points with a *Custom Falloff*.

Comment: not possible without using the custom falloff. just compute a few points using your bump function and set these exact points in the custom falloff so you will have the exact result. if you need there to be an extra falloff drop down option for bump function i'm afraid you will have to modify the blender source code and recompile it.

Comment: Wouldn't computing a few points of the bump function and setting the extra points in the *Custom Falloff* be an approximation of the bump function?

Comment: the question is, what is the problem you are trying to solve? would there really be a visual sculpting difference if you approximated 10 points derived from the bump function that get's you 99% curve accuracy compared to having the exact curve with 99.999999% accuracy?